# Try/Catch doesn't catch exception c#

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

I've try catch exception in this code:

```
    public Source(String source) /// Constructor
    {
        _dialogs = new ThreadSafeList<Int64>();
        _source = source;
        try
        {
            var request = WebRequest.Create(_source);
            var stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(stream);

            _oldNews = doc.SelectNodes("/rss/channel/item").Cast<XmlNode>();
            IsValid = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Logger.Log("Source read error " + source + ", more: " + e.Message);
            IsValid = false;
        }
    }
```

XmlException occurs in try block in doc.Load(stream) but doesn't catch. I find out that exist some exception types that can't be caught in the regular way. XmlException isn't such type of exception. Anyway I tried use [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions] attribute and that won't help. How can i catch this exception? [Stack Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NrQ4o.png). I'll appriciate any suggestions

Comment: How do you know that an XMLException is occurring?

Comment: Are you sure the exception is thrown from inside of that `try` and not at another location?  Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if it's a duplicate (because the underlying cause may be different), but this answer seems to be very useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1405510/328193

Comment: he is using placing the `doc.Load(stream)` inside the block so it does not seem to be the problem

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but `catch (Exception e)` is considered bad practice. You should narrow the scope of your catch block (after you've figured out why it's not working for you). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3866567/211627

Comment: This is relatively unlikely, but could the exception actually be thrown where you iterate through `_oldNews`?  Anyway, you should include the Message and StackTrace from the exception. That would be very helpful.

Comment: Which line is the exception occurring on?

Comment: One other things: What is "IsValid?" The reason I ask is that, in my opinion, it's usually a bad practice to have a constructor that might leave your object in an invalid state because callers might forget to check the IsValid property; it's better to just throw an exception and let the caller handle it correctly, especially since the "log and swallow" approach doesn't give the caller any information about what went wrong (even if they do check IsValid), which makes debugging more difficult. It's also better, @JDB mentioned, to catch specific exceptions.

Comment: @JDB"System.Xml.XmlException" in System.Xml.dll in doc.Load(stream) that how do i know that XmlExeption occuring

Comment: @Druuus - Thanks. Please edit that into your question. The relevant portion of your stack trace would be useful (at least to the Source ctor call... showing that the error is indeed in your constructor)

Answer (score 0):

All the exception in the C# are derived from System.Exception. So, it is not possible for XmlException to be not caught using your code for try and catch.

Assumptions:
a) The exception that you are trying to catch is occurring somewhere else like duplicated code in other module.

b) In case you want to catch XMLException explicitly the below code will help.

```
public static void Source(String source) /// Constructor
{
    try
    {
        var request = WebRequest.Create(source);
        var stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();         
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(stream);
    }
    catch(XmlException e) 
    {
       Console.WriteLine("XmlException Caught");
       Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
       Console.WriteLine("Exception object Line, pos: (" + e.LineNumber + "," + e.LinePosition  + ")");
    }       
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exception Caught");
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a snapshot of the error? Or anything that makes you sure that an Exception is occurring for sure. I am sure that will be very helpful.